# 600k of option_name "c_facebook_background_product_sync_job"

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I have disabled my facebook for woocommerce plugin and I issued this command in phpmyadmin:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM wp_options 
WHERE option_name LIKE 'wc_facebook_background_product_sync_job_%' 
AND (   option_value LIKE '%\"status\":\"queued\"%' 
     OR option_value LIKE '%\"status\":\"processing\"%' )
```

The result I got is:

```
*** row 1 ***
          table:  wp_options
           type:  ALL
  possible_keys:  option_name
            key:  NULL
        key_len:  NULL
            ref:  NULL
           rows:  590455
          Extra:  Using where
```

How do I delete all of these rows quickly using a mysql command that will work?

Answer (score 2):

Use phpmyadmin to make a backup of the `wp_options` table.

Then run the same command again, but replace `SELECT COUNT(*)` with `DELETE`